# Using Template Type with different viewHolder in RecylclerView

Tags: java, android

I have `RecylerView` which have three different kind of `viewHolder` all are extends from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder

- `ImageViewHolder`
- `VideoViewHolder`
- `TextViewHolder`

I create a function for animation. I need to pass `viewHolder` as a parameter in this function. Because there is three different viewHolder I need to create three different animation function ? or I can pass different type of viewHolder in same function.

Here is my animation function.

```
private void runEnterAnimation(final ImageViewHolder holder) {
    final int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(holder.itemView.getContext());
    holder.itemView.setTranslationY(screenHeight);
    holder.itemView.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
            .setDuration(700)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    dispatchAddFinished(holder);
                }
            })
            .start();
}
```

**Running this animation**

```
runEnterAnimation((ImageViewHolder) viewHolder);
```

I try to convert this function into template variable but not working.
Animation with template `T` type

```
private<T> void runEnterAnimation(final T holder) {
//.... } // not working, can not resolve symbol itemView
```

Can you please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Why not simply declare the parameter as type `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`?

Comment: Is that work ??

Comment: And If I don't want to pass `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is it a way to pass with **Template Type** `T` ?